# Using Javascript to load image into a div onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I've been trying for two days to figure out what I am doing wrong. I really think that this code should work, but it doesn't.  If I swap out the variable on line 57 it will bring up a file onClick. So logically the problem is the variable. But when I trace the variable on line 60, the variable is returning the correct value. So why won't the image load correctly? When I click on the button, simply nothing happens.

++EDIT++

I've tried a bunch of things, and the problem is absolutely with the variable $file.  No matter how I test it, $file corresponds to the id number of the item on the list. But when I hit the button, it always pulls item 1. I even went back and edited the code to read:

```
<img id="loadingImage" src="../maps/<?php echo $name['id']?>.gif" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

There is no reason on earth that I can find that this isn't working. 'id' is iterating properly. So why does it think 'id'=1 only after I hit the button?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>List of Parks</title>
        <link href="guide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        <!--
        function showImage() {
            document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        -->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="state"></div>

            <div id="list">
                <?php foreach ($datas as $name):
                {
                    if ($name['state'] == 'PA')
                    {
                ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $name['id']; ?>">

                <h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></h2>
                <?php htmlspecialchars($name['site'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
                <?php $link = $name['site']; ?>
                <ul id="link">
                    <li class="l1"><?php echo "<a href=$link>$link</a>" ?></li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['street'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
                <br>
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['city'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?> ,
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['state'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['zip'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>

                <?php $file = $name['id'];
                $image = '../maps/'.$file.'.gif';?>
                <input type="button" value="click for map" onclick="showImage();" />

                <div id="trailmap">
                    **<img id="loadingImage" src="<?php $image ?>" style="visibility:hidden" />**
                </div>

                <?php echo $image?>

                <hr width="100%" size="3" black />


                <?php
                    }
                }
                endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="fixbox">
            <div id="statemap"></div>
            <div id="home"></div>
            <div id="guide"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the variable $image always contain a standard width and heigth or are they variable?

Comment: Ids need to be unique per document. Do I read your code right that you are generating multiple items in a PHP loop?

Comment: The variable $image is always the same width and height.

Comment: I am generating multiple items in a PHP loop. The id corresponds with the file name. so the path is ../maps/1.gif  for item 1 and ../maps/2.gif for item 2. The button is displayed below the information for that item, and when you hit the button I want an image corresponding to go into a div.

Comment: I can see that I missed "echo" in the line in question. However, now all it does is load ../maps/1.gif no matter which button I hit.